# Trying to pass parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to pass URL params into my Rails app (Ex: /entries/new?name=asdf

Controller:

`def new
    @entry = Entry.new(params[:name])
end
def create
    @entry = Entry.new(params[:name])
      if @entry.save
        redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.'
      else
        render :new
      end
  end`

```
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_entry
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
end
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:name)
end end
```

Form field :

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
```

I'm getting the error "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is a Hash. `params[:name]` will return a string ('asdf' in your example above). When instantiating `Entry` you're only passing the string when you should be passing a hash. Assuming that `name` is an attribute on your Entry model, you'll need to do this

```
@entry = Entry.new(name: params[:name])
```

Comment: One more thing, what if I need to pass in more than one thing, such as a idea_id attribute. How would this work to have multiple attributes passed in through params

Comment: @maclover7 That depends. If you're passing data through GET params (e.g. `/entries/new?name=asdf&idea_id=7`) then both can be accessed from the `params` Hash (e.g. `params[:name]` and `params[:idea_id]`)

Comment: @entry = Entry.new(name: params[:name])(idea_id: params[:idea_id])

Comment: @maclover7 No. Remember that you need to pass a Hash into the `new` method. So in your case that would be `@entry = Entry.new(name: params[:name], idea_id: params[:idea_id])`. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as answered. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use `rails generate scaffold Entry` and take a look to the generated code. What you're trying to do don't have much sense